# PHP: Last data row won't show in pdo GET query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi Guys I am trying to get data with pdo from my table but the last inserted row never shows up in the populated table. When I add another row of data then get the data again to populate I then see the data from the row that previously was'nt showing but then the very last inserted row does not show.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 # This program will allow an admin to see email stats for a certain user
 $userid = 1; // admin

 $email_to = 2 // employee id
 $email_by = 2 // employee id

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = :user_id AND (person = :email_to OR person = :email_by) ORDER BY date DESC";

 $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindparam(":userid", $userid);
 $stmt->bindparam(":email_to", $email_to);
 $stmt->bindparam(":email_by", $email_by);
 $stmt->execute();

 if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // gives me the expected number of rows

  while ($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  echo '<tr><td style="text-align:left;">' . $data['email_subject']
  . '</td><td>' . $data['email_date'] . '</td><td>'
  . $data['email_time'] . '</td></tr>';
 }
} else {
echo "Sorry, no record found.";
}

?>
```

As commented in the code, the `rowCount()` does give me the expected number of rows `e.g. 10,` but in the populated table results I only see `9 rows`.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: use fetchAll() and then check the returned array to see whether any data was returned

Answer (score 0):

It's because you unintentionally skip the first row by the if statement:

```
if ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ...
```

where you assign it to nothing. You may use

```
do {} while ()
```

loop instead.

Comment: Works! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Ros it's wrong idea to use do while instead of while